# C_programming: Static_function_Problem

Tags: c

If I Call a function in one file and in another one I define the function then..I want to perform the static function so that it statically bound within the file...then its not seems to be done successfully....?

I create a file (A.c) with calling a function func():

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "B.c"

int func(int a, int b);  // Function declaration

int main(){
    system("cls");
    int sum = func(3, 4);
    printf("%d", sum);
    

return 0;
}
```

Then I also create a file (B.c) to defining the function fun():

```
int func(int a, int b){  // Function definition
    int c;
    c = a + b;
    return c;
}
```

But if I change the storage class of function to static in (B.c)file then it also show me the output.How it can be done if we change the storage class to static ?
We should get the output as:

```
undefined reference to `func'                               
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status.
```

Here is the after code in (B.c)file:

```
static int func(int a, int b){  // Function definition
    int c;
    c = a + b;
    return c;
}
```

Note : These both files are in the same Folder and performed on the VScode Editor.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include "B.c"
```

You include the `C` file so there is only **one** compilation unit and static functions are visible in this unit. Basically, the content of the file `B.c` is inserted into the `A.c` file and the compiler is compiling one file.

> we change the storage class to static

It is not the storage class, only the linkage. `static` functions do not have *external linkage*

To get the behaviour required (ie unresolved symbols) you need to have two separate compilation units and after the compilation, they have to be **linked together**

In your example remove the `#include "B.c"` and it will stop to link

Generally, **never** include '.c' files or define functions or data in the header files.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem statement is not very clear. The following program [compiles for  me](https://www.godbolt.org/z/KE9s1EM9a):

```
static void f() { } // <-- your B.c

void f(); 
int main() { f(); }
```

That is the compressed version of what you did (your static function definition resides in B.c which you include, and you have a non-static declaration of the same function).

You can certainly put static function definitions in a header and include that header wherever needed. Of course you duplicate the code; on the other hand you give the compiler a chance to inline the function if it is short.

There is a peculiarity with static functions: Each "incarnation" of a static function has its own set of function-static variables (those which persist across calls).

[Here is a somewhat elaborate example](https://www.godbolt.org/z/P1EEq6zzx) of how function-static variables work for static and global functions. It probably looks a bit confusing at first; simply follow the calls though and you'll see what goes on. In particular, the output of `static_g()` "static_g(...) called x times" is not monotonous; it starts back at 1 when it is called from a different translation unit because it is essentially a different function. The compiler would not mind if the implementation of `static_g()` was different in each translation unit. That becomes clear also when you look at the function address: It is different for each calling translation unit. As the example demonstrates, that is not the case with external functions: There is always only one.

Answer (score 1):

`#include "B.c"` seems absurd to me. Usually header files are included this way. This code fragment was giving an error like `multiple definition of 'func'` on my device. This situation can be solved in two ways;

- Remove `#include "B.c"`
- compile as `gcc main.c` not `gcc main.c B.c`

###### The reason why we don't get an error when `static` is this;

If we define the functions in B.c as `static`, they can only be used in B.c. For this reason, when we write `static`, the `#include "B.c"` statement does not cause the function to be defined again.

Answer (score 1):

It is almost never correct practice to `#include` .c files.

When determining scope, the C compiler doesn't actually work on files as such, but on "translation units". That is, the results after all files have gone through pre-processing.

In a normal C program, a translation unit consists of a .c file and all the headers included by that .c file. The preprocessor forms the translation unit by taking the .c file and then inserting all the contents of included files inside that one. You can think of it as an invisible, temporary file only used by the compiler. (You can actually view what it would look like by compiling with `gcc -E`, then view the preprocessed results.)

`static` works on translation units, not .c files. Although if your program design is sound, there is only one .c file per translation unit.

The correct solution is therefore:

- Create a B.h header.
- Put the function declaration `int func(int a, int b);` in B.h
- From A.c, `#include "B.h"`.
- Link A.c and B.c.

Now A.c does not have access to `static` objects/functions in B.c.

Comment: Actually, before you link the files you should compile them (and link the resulting object files) ;-). Also, ideally I'd include B.h also in B.c; this avoids inadvertent changes to the function signature on the implementation side without updating the caller side: The compiler will complain when you compile the (changed) implementation if you *didn't* update the header, and when you compile the caller if you *did* but still call the wrong way, because C does not know overloading.

Comment: I'm not sure the question includes the full story. Because A.c takes the unconventional step of `#include`ing a .c file (B.c) I'd expect the call to `func` in A.c to find the definition whether `static` or not. I'm guessing there are other files in the program and some of those reference `func` and they're causing the linkage failure.